# Show the owner of the question all the time in the question list

Tags: feature-request

As a Stack Overflow user I want to see the owner of the question all the time in the question list , right now it only shows the one who last edited the question.

I feel there is enough space in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) list to show the owner of question with the one who edited it last.

OK , I understand we really not require to see all the editors but it would be great to see owner of the question all the time because then you can decide to go and see the detail or not because sometimes you want to give time to questions specific to your experience and asked by reputed person when don't have much time to spend on reading simple questions that can be answered by others easily.

Comment: You can always click on the `edited` link to see the revision list (tells you _exactly_ who edited and when).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would like to chime in here and mention that the original poster of the question is **irrelevant** in any case.

Why would one want to know who asked the question -

- Will it make you look at the question differently?
- Will you misunderstand the question because you do not know exactly who asked it?
- Would knowing who asked the question affect your decision to answer it?

If the answer to **any**  of those is yes then I'm afraid you are not looking at the content on Stack Overflow in the right way... Content on the site should stand on its own merit.  The user who is attached to that post has nothing to do with the validity of the question*.

**Content is content no matter what user submitted the post.**  Think about a situation where a user posts a terribly formatted and worded question... The community will jump on that post, make edits, retag, etc.. until the question is much much better and meets our high quality standards.  Other than thinking up the question, the original poster had nothing to do with the final outcome of his post - tags were added, formatting was changed, etc...

---

I'd like to address one statement you made -

> you want to give time to questions specific to your experience and asked by reputed person

A reputed person (I assume from the context) is a user with a relatively high reputation.  Think about this - I have [most of my rep from ****book questions...](https://stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix?tab=tags) but I have zero knowledge in C#.  I'm able to ask an extremely complex ****book FQL/Graph API question but I might ask a painfully simple C# question...  A high rep user can still ask simple simple questions in a field that he is not experienced... So you see - the user doesn't really matter here - its the content of the question you need to look at...

---

So you see, the fact that you *want* to see who originally posted the question (before even looking at the question) is the wrong way to go about things... Judge questions by their content and not by the users...

* <sub>Unless of course the same user is re-posting questions.</sub>

Comment: I agree that the original poster is irrelevant, but then what information does naming the last editor contain? Why would I want to see that? If every contributor plays a similar role in shaping the question, then showing nothing but a "history" popover would be the least misleading, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 11):

The "owner" of the question (or at least, the person who originally posted it) is already shown in that list.

Why in the world would we want to show the names of the last 3–4 editors? What useful purpose would that serve? Why would you need to know that information? How would it ever help you to determine whether to view a question or not?

> I feel there is enough space in the question list

I don't see how you've arrived at that conclusion. Here's a mockup of what it might look like on a random question stolen from the front page, along with some random "editors":

[image]

Not only is that cluttered and ugly, but the three people *barely* fit, and then only because the question only has one tag! Most questions need more than that. In fact, I'll bet that question gets edited in short order to have at least 3 tags, which would mean we could only show *one* more user's gravatar there in addition to the original poster.

Remind me again what purpose this serves?

Comment: I just can't spend much time on the questions which are not clear by subject but seems relative to my experience and ask by the new person , instead I prefer to go in detail for reputed person's question, thats my choice.

Comment: So how would it help to know who has *edited* the question? They're not the ones who asked it. That doesn't tell you anything about the difficulty of the question. (Also, is it really that hard to, you know, *read the question*?)

Comment: Ya that does not actually help much, but as they thought something to show them and already implemented , I just don't want them to get rid of it. edited question title and body

Comment: @imr - Just because a high rep user asks a question - it doesn't mean it's gonna be an interesting or complicated question...

Comment: hmm then we finding out a way to know this would be a helpful

Comment: @imr - you'd have to actually look at the post to figure that out...